# No exportfs CLI on OS X

Tags: nfs

On Linux, there is `exportfs` CLI tool which can be used to export NFSs without modifying `/etc/exports` file. However, I can't find it on OS X 10.8.

Why is it missing? Is there any way to install it or simulate its functionality: dynamically (un)export filesystems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no cli tools for this (not in homebrew, fink or MacPorts). Even the [Apple documentation on configuring NFS exports](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4695) talks about using a text editor to manipulate `/etc/exports` directly.

There is an older user created shell script for [exportfs for Mac OS X](http://www.hanynet.com/nfs/howto-macosx.html). The download link on that page is broken, but the script is available on the archive.org page at [mac exportfs](http://web.archive.org/web/20100731124053/http://www.ceci.at/mac/exportfs). One issue that I noticed is that this script uses the outdated (and unavailable) `niutil` command for the NetInfo database. You could try using this script as a starting point and modify it to use [dscl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html) instead of `niutil`.